# CASE count values when they are not a date

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have a SELECT query where one of the fields looks like this:

```
SomeField
1775889
2014-10-01
1775889
1234567
2569874
5552789
2013-09-06
```

I need to count the distinct number of non date values. Something like

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN SomeField != Date THEN SomeField END),
```

In this example, when it comes to aggregating SomeField, I'd the number 4 returned since there are 4 distinct non date values. How would I do this?

Comment: Pass the column to STR_TO_DATE() with your expected format, invalids will be NULL

Comment: @AlexK. That's worth an answer I think...

Comment: @AlexK, Wouldn't NULL's be counted then as well? Don't know how mysql deals with NULL...

Comment: Nope, `NULL` wont be counted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the column to `STR_TO_DATE()` with your expected format, invalids will be NULL

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT SomeField)
FROM 
    T
WHERE
    STR_TO_DATE(SomeField, '%Y-%m-%d') IS NULL
```

Comment: So this would count all the dates, the OP is asking for a count of the non-dates

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does this not do the inverse of what I need? It runs but the data are not what I was expecting. Is this counting the distinct number of date values or the distinct number of non date values? Ah, yes just saw @HoneyBadger comment after typing this

Comment: Maybe something like: COUNT(CASE WHEN STR_TO_DATE(SomeField, '%Y-%m-%d') IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)? This doens't take DISTINCT into account, though

Comment: @AlexK. thanks but for this particular query distinct values is important since I know there is a lot of duplication

Comment: @AlexK. it's returning 0s when I know there should be data. This is how it actually looks (the whole thing is within a larger query so cannot use WHERE condition:
SELECT cats, dogs, stuff, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN STR_TO_DATE(my2.data, '%Y-%m-%d') IS NULL THEN my2.data END) AS CountTheThing

Comment: How about `COUNT(DISTINCT SomeField) - COUNT(DISTINCT STR_TO_DATE(SomeField, '%Y-%m-%d'))`

Comment: Actually I made an error a step back ago. Your solution does indeed work. Thank you so very much

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM TABLE T
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(SomeField , '%Y-%m-%d')='0000-00-00'
GROUP BY SomeField
```

According to [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

*Unspecified date or time parts have a value of 0, so incompletely specified values in str produce a result with some or all parts set to 0*

Comment: Thanks for responding. Tried that and it produced 0 for all records